# Matrix multiplication with arduino and eigen not working

Tags: arduino, eigen, arduino-ide

I know using `#include <stlport.h>` and `#include <Eigen30.h>` to make **Eigen** work with Arduino is a pretty old way to get working **Eigen**.

Hence I tried also `#include <ArduinoSTL.h>` with two Eigen Arduino libs that I found out there(`#include <Eigen30.h>` and `#include <Eigen.h>`). I´ll leave here the links to the **GitHub** repos of all the libraries.

`#include <Eigen.h>` : https://github.com/bolderflight/Eigen

`#include <Eigen30.h>`: https://github.com/vancegroup/EigenArduino/tree/Eigen30

`#include <stlport.h>`: https://github.com/vancegroup/stlport-avr/tree/STLport-5.2-arduino-installed

`#include <ArduinoSTL.h>` : https://github.com/mike-matera/ArduinoSTL



Only `#include <stlport.h>` and `#include <Eigen30.h>` actually compiled in Arduino's IDE. I'm Actually `version 1.6.20` of the **AVR Boards** package that we can modify in **Tools** **Board** **Board Manager**.

When I started doing some basic operations to test **Eigen**, like adding matrices and Initializing matrices. Then I noticed that whenever I multiplied 2 matrices no matter the method I used (I tried every method that the documentation of Eigen suggested as best practices) the program got stuck in that specific instruction.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stlport.h>
#include <Eigen30.h>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace Eigen;

void setup()
{
   Serial.begin(9600);
   delay(2000);
   Serial.print("Hi");

Matrix3f m;
MatrixXf b(2,2);
MatrixXf M1(2,2); //EDIT: I missed this last time.
MatrixXf matA(2, 2);

 m << 1, 2, 3,
      4, 5, 6,
      7, 8, 9;

matA << 1, 2,
        1, 2;

b = matA;

 print_mtxf(b);  // Goes ok
 print_mtxf(matA);  // Goes ok

Serial.print("M1:\n");  // Goes ok
 M1.noalias() =  matA*b;  // Something wrong is going on here.
 print_mtxf(M1);  // Nerver gets to print this or the following
 Serial.print("M1:\n");
 Serial.print("M1:\n");

}

void loop()
{

}

void print_mtxf(const Eigen::MatrixXf &X)  
{
   int i, j, nrow, ncol;

   nrow = X.rows();
   ncol = X.cols();

   Serial.print("nrow: "); Serial.println(nrow);
   Serial.print("ncol: "); Serial.println(ncol);       
   Serial.println();

   for (i=0; i<nrow; i++)
   {
       for (j=0; j<ncol; j++)
       {
           Serial.print(X(i,j), 6);   // print 6 decimal places
           Serial.print(", ");
       }
       Serial.println();
   }
   Serial.println();
}
```

So now what are my options? I really want to get working **Eigen** because I'm going to use a basic c++ library that depends just in Eigen, it's pretty basic but **Eigen** hasn't worked properly. I think it gest to an infinite loop because the proceeding prints never get completed.

Comment: What is `M1`? Make sure to post the actual code you tried to compile. Also, how does it fail? Does it get stuck in an infinite loop? Does it crash/assert?

Comment: Also, first try to only `#include <Eigen/Core>` (which I guess is already included by `"Eigen30.h"`). If you manage to have that working, try out other modules and report issues you are getting to whoever maintains `Eigen30.h`. Alternatively, try an up-to-date Eigen release and report issues you are getting at any Eigen support channel.

Comment: Sorry M1 is another matrix, I missed pasting that part of the code.

Comment: No idea what is happening. Did you try removing the `#include <Eigen/Dense>`? Does `Matrix2f` instead of `MatrixXf` work? What happens if you include an up-to-date `Eigen/Core` instead of `Eigen30.h` (with or without first including (`stlport.h`)?